# Modal Box Opens on CodePen but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im experienceing a very odd issue, Im trying to make a modal box open on my localhost but it doesn't work. I tired putting my code into codepen and it works with out a problem. Im not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I copied the example out of W3schools so it should work with out a problem.

https://codepen.io/dsflyerds/pen/wvddOvg

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Modal Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/modal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the paths to the CSS and JS file are correct on your localhost. Besides, do you see anything on the console of your localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your script tag in your head, yet you are not ***defering*** the script to wait until the DOM has loaded.

Read the following for more information: [Script Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Modal Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style/style.css">
     <!--/ Add defer ==> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate 
     to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after 
      the document has been parsed /-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/modal.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Some will add the script tag under all the pages HTML within the `body` tag to make sure the HTML content is loaded before the JavaScript is run.

```
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
        </p>
        <!--/ script can be added here and will load after  
              the body's content is loaded in the DOM /-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="style/modal.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```